# AES encryption and decryption Expo project (react native) on Managed workflow?

Tags: react-native, expo

What is the best way to use Aes encryption/decryption on an Expo project without ejecting it (without going to react native like or bare Workflow) ?

at first i was tempted to use [react-native-aes](https://github.com/tectiv3/react-native-aes), but this use the NativeModules. does a pure vanilla JS (like crypto-js with no node dependency because of iOs issus) could be the proper solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved

I used Crypto-js@3.1 that has no Node dependency, worked on Android and iOs